# how to scroll and click the desired element while not able to get the value of that element

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, selenium, discord

I'm having a problem trying to make an auto-register for Discord account, after opening the browser and filling in the necessary information, it comes to choosing the date of birth.
Well, here's the problem! Every item that selects the day, month, and year will be a dropbox, and I can't get the values inside that dropbox to scroll or click. I have tried using the wait command to wait for the values to appear, and locate the option I want to select using its text content. But it's not working at all, can someone help me

```
import imaplib
import email
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
from time import sleep
import requests
import pandas as pd
from solveRecaptcha import solveRecaptcha
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import *

df = pd.read_excel('discord.xlsx')

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    
    # Hotmail information get from Excel
    Mailname = row['Mail']
    Mailpass = row['Passmail']
    # Discord information get from Excel
    DCusername = row['Dcusername']
    DCpassword = row['Dcpass']

    # Change IP by proxy server API and print status
    response = requests.get("https://app.proxyno1.com/api/change-key-ip/my-apikey")
    status = response.json()["message"]
    print('Status:', status)
    sleep(10)
    # Create a proxy object with the updated proxy URL
    proxy = Proxy({
        'proxyType': ProxyType.MANUAL,
        'httpProxy': 'vpdc1.proxyno1.com:19548',
        'sslProxy': 'vpdc1.proxyno1.com:19548',
        'noProxy': ''})

    # Update the capabilities object to use the new proxy
    capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
    proxy.add_to_capabilities(capabilities)

    # Open the signup page with proxy
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=capabilities)
    driver.get("https://discord.com/register")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.NAME, "email"))
    )
    driver.find_element(By.NAME, "email").send_keys(Mailname)
    driver.find_element(By.NAME, "username").send_keys(DCusername)
    driver.find_element(By.NAME, "password").send_keys(DCpassword)
    month_element = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "month-1Z2bRu").click()
    # Wait for the dropdown menu options to be fully loaded
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    options = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//option")))

    # Locate the option to select using its text content
    option = next(option for option in options if option.text == "May")

    # Select the option by clicking on it
    option.click()
    sleep(77)
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: What does the `options` variable contains once the `wait.until...` line is done? Did you try printing it?

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak it fails to start from that command line, the error appears "Exception has occurred: TimeoutException"

Comment: Oh, then maybe it can not find any option elements. Maybe the page is not using `option` elements? Did you inspect the page to check what kind of elements show up?

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak it seems to be a hidden element, I checked and when I click on "Month" an element named "css-13qdo4d-menu" appears. And that's the menu of the months I need to click, but every time I click anywhere else, including the f12 table, that box automatically disappears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code, I've added the code to select a month, day, and year:

```
# you can change the month, day, and year
month_to_select = "October"    # month name should start with capital
day_to_select = "22"
year_to_select = "1905" 

# to select Month
month_dropdown = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(.//*[@class='css-19vtg9u-control'])[1]")
month_dropdown.click()
time.sleep(1)

month_all = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, ".//*[contains(@id,'react-select-2-option-')]")

i = 0
for month in month_all:
    month_ele = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//*[contains(@id,'react-select-2-option-" + str(i) + "')]")
    if month_to_select == month_ele.text:
        month_ele.click()
        break
    i += 1

# to select Day
day_dropdown = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(.//*[@class='css-19vtg9u-control'])[2]")
day_dropdown.click()
time.sleep(1)

day_all = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, ".//*[contains(@id,'react-select-3-option-')]")

j = 0
for day in day_all:
    day_ele = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//*[contains(@id,'react-select-3-option-" + str(j) + "')]")
    if day_to_select == day_ele.text:
        day_ele.click()
        break
    j += 1

# to select Year
year_dropdown = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(.//*[@class='css-19vtg9u-control'])[3]")
year_dropdown.click()
time.sleep(1)

year_all = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, ".//*[contains(@id,'react-select-4-option-')]")

k = 0
for year in year_all:
    year_ele = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//*[contains(@id,'react-select-4-option-" + str(k) + "')]")
    if year_to_select == year_ele.text:
        year_ele.click()
        break
    k += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to disable JS while the drop-down popup was open to peek at the HTML it adds to the DOM. They do not use `select` and `option` elements, but just `div`. You might be able to find the element based on the ID `react-select-3-option-4` or the text contents.

[image: discord elements in dev tools]

Comment: thank u so much! Can you guide me how to disable it?

Comment: I used the uBlock Chrome extension, which has a button to disable JS on the current page. I first made the popup appear, then disabled JS, and used the dev tools to select the element.